# Changing volume of an audio driver affects balance shift in Mac system

Tags: swift, macos, audio, driver, core-audio

We have our own audio driver developed for Mac, Changing the volume for this driver, shifts its balance. Can someone help me with this?

We set the left and right volume using **kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar**, But this will shift the balance of my audio driver.